# jQuery not updating div content after database update

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am loading a php file in a div using jQuery. The php file displays the content of a MySQL database. It works fine but here is the problem: if I make a change to the database, I add a row for example, the div does not reflect the change. Whatever I do I just see the data as they were the first time I accessed the page.

The code I am using is pretty simple:

```
// This goes into head
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function recp(id) {
$('#myStyle').load('displaydata.php?id=' + id);
}
</script>
// Set id to '1' onload
<body onload="recp('1')">
// Then I have a few links that will change the value of id onclick
<a href="#" onClick="recp('1')">Materials</a> | <a href="#" onClick="recp('2')">Manufacturing</a>
// Finally my div
<div id='myStyle'>
</div>
```

I do not put here the displaydata.php code. Anyway it is just a simple php file that SELECT and ECHO data.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Why the div does not reflect the changes I make to the MySQL database? Thanks.

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: also make sure the request is reaching your server

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to think of a problem in terms of caching. If you are okay with moving away from `load` method, you could take a look at following code and make it into a right use.

```
var recp = function(id) {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/displaydata.php?id=' + id,
      cache: false,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
          $('#myStyle').html(data);
      }
  });
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Dachi. I will try first to clear my browser cache to see if it is coming from here (but I am afraid it is only a temporary fix...). If not I will try the code you suggested. Question: I see that in your code you use cache: false. Will it tell ajax to ignore what is in the browser cache? If so it could be the definite answer to my problem. Thanks again for your help :-)

Comment: According to official documentation about jQuery's `cache` property `If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.` Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is your php page cached? If you're making changes to the database behind the scenes, you need to clear your cache.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. It is very likely that the problem comes from cache (I opened another thread about a totally different problem I had on my computer and people also suggested I have to clear my cache). I will clear my cache and see if it works. Thanks again.